# C++20 std::span: Uses of converting constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++20, std-span

The converting constructor of C++ std::span of the form:

```
template<class OtherElementType, size_t OtherExtent>
  constexpr explicit(see below) span(
     const span<OtherElementType, OtherExtent>& s) noexcept;
```

with [constraints](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/views#span.cons-19), can be used for the following purposes:

```
int arr[]{1, 2, 3};

span<int, 3> sf{arr};
// static span to dynamic span.
span<int> sd{sf};

// non-const to const span.
span<const int> scd{sd};
span<const int, 3> sfc{sf};

// dynamic to static span.
span<int, 3> sf2{sd};
```

What are some of the other uses this constructor which satisfy [this constraint](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/views#span.cons-19.2)?

`is_­convertible_­v<OtherElementType(*)[], element_­type(*)[]>` is true. [ Note: The intent is to allow only qualification conversions of the `OtherElementType` to `element_­type`. — end note ]

Comment: As the note says it allows for _any_ qualification conversion, e.g. `int**` to `int const* const* const`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to allow implicitly converting between spans, as long as this conversion is a qualifying conversion and the sizes match.
It can also be used for explicit conversions like in your exaples, but (8) is special because it's `explicit` only in a few cases. For example:

```cpp
void process_all(std::span<const int> numbers);

std::span<int> get_range();

void foo() {
    auto r = get_range(); // ok, sizes match and qualifying conversion takes place
    process_all(r);
}
```

This is possible, because there is a qualifying conversion from `int` to `const int`, so we can convert `std::span<int>` to `std::span<const int>`.
This use case is quite common, because making `const std::span<T>` doesn't ensure immutability of the elements, only a `std::span<const T>` does that.

This qualifying conversion can actually be multiple levels deep, e.g. we can:

- take a `std::span<const int * const * const>` as a function parameter
- pass a `std::span<int**>` to it

However, that's not a unique property of this constructor, (7) does the same.
You may ask: *"Why don't we just use constructor (7)?"*

```cpp
template< class R >
explicit(extent != std::dynamic_extent)
constexpr span( R&& range ); // (7)
```

This constructor works with any sized contiguous range, and a span is one.
However, it is always explicit for a static extent, and only constructor (8) allows an implicit conversion between equally sized static spans. For example:

```cpp
#include <span>

void process_all(std::span<const int, 100> numbers);

std::span<int, 100> get_range();
std::span<int, 10> get_short_range();
std::span<int> get_dynamic_range();

void foo() {
    process_all(get_range());         // OK
    process_all(get_short_range());   // ill-formed, need explicit conversion
    process_all(get_dynamic_range()); // ill-formed, need explicit conversion
}
```

The examples that you've given all use explicit conversions, so they don't demonstrate what makes (8) special, namely that it's conditionally explicit in fewer situations than other constructors.